# How can we access the one file variable into another file without using SESSION and INCLUDE in php

Tags: php, html

I want to access the test1.php file variable `$var1` in test2.php without using `sessions` or `include`. I looked at many questions related to this, but I didnt find exactly what I want.

test1.php:

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="text">        
        <?php
        $var1="Hello World";
        echo $var1;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

test2.php:

```html
<input type="text" name="text2" value="<?php echo $var1;?>"
```

When I run test2.php I want to print `Hello world` in the text field. If I use `include` that will print the text field in test1.php, so i don't want any html element to be printed, I only need the variable and its value.

Comment: You can send it with a form using `GET` like `test2.php?var1=Hello Word` or using `POST`.

Comment: you have to pass the variable in any way to the next page. If you don't want to use Sessions and include than you have to do something like a form and send it via $_GET. But you have to know that it's impossible to try to pass a variable to another page but not using any of the passing functions or techniques or variables. It's like you're hungry and want to get full but say: hey I want to get full but I don't want to use food for this.

Comment: There are few options - COOKIE, SESSION, CLASS variable or like GET/POST parameter. Otherwhise simply you cannot do that.

Comment: Not possible without PHP's GLOBAL variable and include

Comment: You don't need a GLOBAL @MineshPatel

Comment: I am referring to $_GLOBAL

Comment: @JayBlanchard then please give answer without using $_GLOBAL and include

Comment: I can use GET or POST @MineshPatel and this would meet the OP's requirements of not using includes or session variables.

Comment: That question has nothing to do with this question @MineshPatel

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry but $_GLOBAL include these all variables ($_GET,$_POST,$_SESSION,$_SERVER,$_COOKIE,$_ENV....)

Comment: There is no such thing as `$_GLOBAL` @MineshPatel. Are you referring to the super global `$GLOBALS`? `$_GET` and `$_POST` are super globals too, but not part of `$GLOBALS`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes that question has nothing to do with this question but look at that and suggest if you have any solution

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes super global

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry it's my bad it should be "$GLOBALS" and not $_GLOBAL

Comment: @JayBlanchard also i have removed my link as well